# Failed to create an instance of io.testproject.sdk.drivers.web.ChromeDriver

Tags: java, exception, testproject.io

I got this error when trying to run Testproject sdk.
TestProject agent is running perfectly.
The token also working perfectly.
I tried to find a solution online but I couldn't find any soulution to this error.

```
 public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    ChromeDriver driver = new DriverBuilder<ChromeDriver>(new ChromeOptions())
            .withRemoteAddress(new URL("http://localhost:8585"))
            .withToken("XXX")
            .build(ChromeDriver.class);

    driver.navigate().to("https://example.testproject.io/web/");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#name")).sendKeys("John Smith");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#password")).sendKeys("12345");
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login")).click();
    boolean passed = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#logout")).isDisplayed();
    if (passed) {
        System.out.println("Test Passed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
    }
    driver.quit();
```

And the error message is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to create an instance of io.testproject.sdk.drivers.web.ChromeDriver
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'S01128', ip: '192.168.42.18', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at io.testproject.sdk.DriverBuilder.build(DriverBuilder.java:263)
    at DemoClass.main(DemoClass.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at io.testproject.sdk.DriverBuilder.build(DriverBuilder.java:251)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/config/Lookup
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.custom(HttpClients.java:48)
    at io.testproject.sdk.internal.rest.AgentClient.<init>(AgentClient.java:270)
    at io.testproject.sdk.internal.rest.AgentClient.getClient(AgentClient.java:573)
    at io.testproject.sdk.drivers.web.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:917)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.config.Lookup
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 11 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using JDK 11. Previously I used JDK 17 and then downgraded to 11 but it didn't solve the problem.

Here is the POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>FourWDSupaCentre1.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>16</source>
                    <target>16</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17.0.1</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17.0.1</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.testproject/java-sdk -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.testproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.10</version>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using JDK 17. I would recommend downgrading to JDK 11, it would solve the issue as described [here](https://forum.testproject.io/t/exception-in-thread-main-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-failed-to-create-an-instance-of-io-testproject-sdk-drivers-web-chromedriver-open/6172)

Download OpenJDK 11 from [here](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/9/GPL/openjdk-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin.zip)